# How do you implement BasicHttpAuthentication in grails 2.0 using shiro? Any shinning example?

Tags: grails, groovy, basic-authentication, shiro

My current project set up already has shiro 1.1.4 and it uses login and logout. For instance, the project already set up grails shiro start.The project utilizes securityFilter.groovy, AuthController.groovy, and BootStrap.groovy. The plugin is configured through BuildConfig.groovy.
Do I need shiro.ini file?
How do I set up a non-interactive login with basic http authentication?

Answer (score 1):

I also use in an old grails 2.4.2 Project the abbility to connect to a few controllers via HttpBasicAuth.

In generall the application is secured through Apache-Shiro, but I have 2 packages/controllers in the application which needs BasicAuth.

Therefore I extendes the UrlMappings.groovy file:

```
class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {
        group("/api") {
            "/api/$action?/$id?(.${format})?"(controller: 'api')
        }

        group("/dw") {
            "/dw/$action?/$id?(.${format})?"(controller: 'dw')
        }
        ...
```

and the Config.groovy with:

```
security {
    shiro {
        authc.required = false
        filter.config = """\
[filters]
# HTTP Basic authentication
authcBasic = org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authc.BasicHttpAuthenticationFilter
authcBasic.applicationName = MyGrailsApp API
[urls]
/api/** = authcBasic
/dw/** = authcBasic
"""
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @susi. How would you avoid API though?

Comment: Hello @Dani , you mean to access everything (every controller and action) through basic-auth? In this case, I would think that you don't need the group-mappings and set /*/** = authBasic ... just a guess...